# How to calculate geometric mean with a square root with a number before it?

Tags: statistics

I know, I sound stupid, but I'm French and I can't think of a way to say it.  Here's the example I have:

In 2008 there were $44$ million pager subscribers. By 2014 the number of subscribers increased to $64$ million. What is the geometric mean annual increase for the period?

Apparently the answer is $6.44%$, so $\frac{64}{44}-1$, and then square root with the variable $6$ before it; I can't figure out how to put this into the calculator and get the same result.

Comment: I believe you are asking:  what is $r$ given that $(1+r)^6\times 44=64$, no?  If so then $r=\left(\frac {64}{44}\right)^{1/6}-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The following is called the sixth root of $\frac{64}{44}$:
$$\sqrt[6]{\frac{64}{44}}=\left(\frac{64}{44}\right)^{1/6}$$